# How should I indicate both my legal name and my nickname in an application?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request, names

I have been known by the name *David* to my friends. If I applied for some stuff using my legal name e.g. *Jainokiv Zub* (the name that matches my ID card), how am I going to tell the other party that my nickname is *David*?

I mean I was told to email a department after I submitted my online application to tell them that I have submitted the application so they can process it. In the email I also wish to inform them that *David* is not on the application form. I want to say something like:

> "Hi, I have sent the application. Please process it. The name of the application is *Jainokiv Zub* (my legal name). *David* is my nickname. Best regards, David"
>
> "Hi, I have sent the application. Please process it. The name of the application is *Jainokiv Zub*. *David* is my nickname. Best regards, David"
>
> "Hi, I have sent the application. Please process it. The name of the application is *Jainokiv Zub.* Best regards, David"

I am not sure if what I have written is correct.

Could someone please help me to write what I wanted to say in better / correct English?

Answer (score 4):

In second paragraph of your question you are explaining clearly the purpose of the message you are trying to put together. I think, you can do just that. You can write something like:

**Hello!**

**My name is David Zub a.k.a Jainokiv Zub. I'm writing this to let you know that I submitted my application under my legal name (Jainokiv Zub) on [date] for your processing.**

**Best regards,**

**David**

**[your contact info]**